# Redux framework issue: How to show output from admin panel to front end

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

I'm new in redux framework. I can't shown a text from admin panel to front end.

I did this step:
I changed this:->
'opt_name' => $zboom,

apply in footer.php:

```
<?php
   global $zboom;
   echo $zboom['copyright-footer'];
?>
```

I think all are ok. My admin panel also working well. Here is my admin panel code:

```
Redux::setSection($opt_name, array(
    'title' => 'Footer Options',
    'desc' => 'Footer Area',
    'icon' => 'el el-cogs',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Footer Copyright',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => 'All Rights Reserved',
            'id' => 'copyright-footer',
            'desc' => 'Footer Copyright Text'

        )
    )

));
```

What is my wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `$opt_name = "zboom"`. Find out line number 13 of your
   sample-config.php page, where the store redux data.
2. Do not change any parameter of `opt_name` in the config file. Do
   the section like this: `Redux::setSection($opt_name, $args)`.
3. To make output in other files do this: `<?php $global $zboom; echo
   $zboom['your-id'] ?>`.